# Iterate map java with generic items

Tags: java, dictionary, generics

i have a maps in java that contains generic value with key string:

```
String value1 = "value";
Long value2 = 100L;

Map<String, ?> items = new HashMap<>();
items.put("key1", value1);
items.put("key2", value2);
```

How can I execute a different method

```
public void customMethod(String str){}
```

or

```
public void customMethod(Long lng){}
```

with foreach map:

```
items.forEach((key, value) -> customMethod(value))?
```

thanks

Comment: `items.put("key1", value1);` wouldn't compile, because the map's value type is unknown. You would need to use `Map<String, Object>`.

Comment: That Map will contain `Object` as value type. This means: you would need a method that takes `Object`, then does `instanceof` and "manually" invokes the corresponding custom method.

Comment: You need to rethink this design.  At the very least you should create a class that can hold the different values and know it's type then use that as your second class type in the map.  Alternatively, have a couple of maps each dealing with a specific value type.

Comment: What's wrong with having multiple maps so that you could segregate values by their type?

Answer (score 1):

Use reflection to dispatch the call to the appropriate method:

```
public void customMethod(Object obj) {
    try {
        getClass().getMethod("customMethod", obj.getClass()).invoke(this, obj);
    } catch (ReflectiveOperationException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

See [live demo](https://ideone.com/aovF2R) running with your examples.

However, this implementation is going to be slow because the method must be looked up every time it's used. To make this production ready, you can lookup the method once and cache and re-use it via its [`MethodHandle`](https://www.baeldung.com/java-method-handles):

```
private static Map<Class<?>, MethodHandle> methodHandleCache = new HashMap<>();

public void customMethod(Object obj) {
    try {
        methodHandleCache.computeIfAbsent(obj.getClass(), this::findMethodHandle).invoke(this, obj);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

private MethodHandle findMethodHandle(Class<?> clazz) {
    try {
        MethodType methodType = MethodType.methodType(void.class, clazz);
        return MethodHandles.lookup().findVirtual(getClass(), "customMethod", methodType);
    } catch (ReflectiveOperationException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

See [live demo](https://ideone.com/uYVQZJ).

Comment: Huuuuuuh. Ugly. The basic rule is: ONLY use reflection if there is no other way. Not only does this add many error paths (that all only show up at runtime) ... when called on scale, this can have significant impact on performance. If you really go for a "dynamic" solution, then: A) create MethodHandle instances for each of the classes you intend to cover B) put those instances into a Map < Class, MethodHandle >. That also allows for a simple check for classes you don't support for example.

Comment: @GhostCat there is nothing evil about reflection. Spring for example is *all* reflection, as is the JRE all the way down. Yes, it can be made performant: This is just a demo of the core idea of an approach. I use reflection regularly for this kind of situation. As for only detecting errors at runtime: Thorough unit and function  testing, which I always do, means errors *never* happen when deployed because there is no code path or scenario in production that hasn’t been tested for prior to release. BTW, code much funkier than this (that I wrote) is currently in production at a major bank.

Comment: *there is nothing evil about reflection.* For the advanced reader that is. People who know exactly what they are doing.I thought we should always remember that we have *no* idea who will be reading our answers in the future. Too much code on this planet is just copied from stackoverflow by people who do **not** understand the potential consequences of your actions. And as said: if you really want to go for reflection, why not show MethodHandles at least?

Comment: *means errors never happen when deployed* .... sorry, but I have a hard time believing that "never" part.

Comment: @GhostCat Challenge accepted - MethodHandle option added. Re bug: Never *so far* from using reflection. I use lots and lots of unit tests, plus the service domain is typically limited - there are a defined and usually quite limited range of types being throw at the code.